# Ice-hockey 6v5 situation

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey, nhl

I am curious how are situations with extra player in ice-hockey handled statistically.
For example, team A is loosing 2:3 and there is one last minute of the match. They switch goalie for an extra player so they have empty net and the situation is 6v5. If they score a goal, will it be an even strength goal? And what if team A was playing short-handed, they had penalty and it was 4v5 situation but after switching player for goalie it would be 5v5. Will it still be a power-play goal? Would it be even strength goal? Or how would be the situation described, just 4v5 or 5v5 (maybe 4+1v5)? And what about 6v4 etc.?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are recorded as a normal, even-strength goal.  See for example [TOR vs MON, Oct 5, 2019](https://www.nhl.com/news/montreal-canadiens-toronto-maple-leafs-game-recap/c-309772834), [Hockey Ref box score](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201910050TOR.html#all_advanced).  Austin Matthews scored the tying goal with the goalie, Michael Hutchinson, pulled; you can only really tell from the box score as Hutchinson has only 64:52 TOI.  Matthews is credited with 2 Even Strength goals.  Even +/- it clearly counts for; add up TOR's +/- and you get a net +1, while adding up MON's +/- you get a net +0 (which makes sense, as both sides had one goal that is excluded, one PPG and one penalty shot, so both sides scored 4 even strength goals - including the one scored with the extra attacker).

Another game from the same season, [CBJ vs BUF, 10/7/2019](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201910070CBJ.html), shows a powerplay goal in that situation - there it is a 6 on 4 goal, if I'm reading it right.  Similarly, it's not really identifiable as anything beyond a normal PP goal, except for the goalie's TOI again being less than that of the other goalie.

In the case it was a 4-on-5 with a pulled goalie, it would be a short handed goal, similarly.  Removing the goalie, at the moment, doesn't change the statistics, other than to have one more player receive a +/- result.

Comment: Often we think about 'even strengh' being 5v5, but actually, its 6v6. The goalie pulling is just a loophole in the rules because the rules never request a goalie to be present (it just would be a garbage strategy to run without a goalie). So its still even strengh because both teams got 6 players on the ice.